# How to add a new column of data using dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset (a long list of values but the form is as shown below) such that
| NO | AC_NAME|
| :--| :----- |
| 0  | X      |
| 1  | Y      |

and a dictionary such that
{'X': 'STRING_DATA1',
'Y': 'STRING_DATA2',
.....}

How can I add the values of the dictionary as a new column in the top dataset where the AC_NAME matches with the dictionary keys? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `map` to map the value from `AC_NAME` to the dictionary, and assign it to a new column.

```py
d = {'X': 'STRING_DATA1',
 'Y': 'STRING_DATA1'}

df.assign(newColumn=df.AC_NAME.map(d))

   NO AC_NAME     newColumn
0   0       X  STRING_DATA1
1   1       Y  STRING_DATA1
```